# How to add InputText in alert component?

Tags: javascript, react-native, alert

I have alert function. And I want to input in alert to confirm this reject confirmation.

```
export const showAlert = (title: string, body: string, buttons = [{ 
   text: 'Ok', onPress: () => {} }]) => {
   Alert.alert(title, body, buttons, { cancelable: true });
};
showAlert(
  t("reject_confirmation"),
  t("are_you_sure_to_reject_from_tasks"),
  [

    {
      text: t("cancel"),
      onPress: () => {},
    },

    {
      text: t("global_reject"),
      onPress: async () => {
        await this.runActionWithLoad(async () => {
          const url = "/Task/RejectByVillage";
          await request().post(url, { villageId, taskType: type });
          showToast(this.t("global_action_success"));
        });
      },
    },
  ]
);
```

In alert function I want to add `<TextInput/>` from react-native

Comment: you can use Modal instead of Alert .

Comment: If I will use Modal, I need to change mostly code in project, so I have to find some way to use `<TextInput>`

Comment: You will not be able to insert Textinput inside Alert since Alert doesnt support it. You will need to use modal. Changing your code will be better instead of going to wrong approach.